# Progress dialog not showing in Async task android

Tags: android, facebook, progressdialog

I am using Facebook SDK to upload photos to Facebook. While the photos are uploading I want to show a progress dialog, and I am facing a strange issue.

When I declare the `ProgressDialog` in the `onPreExecute()` method, the dialog box is shown.

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Second.this);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
    dialog.show();
}
```

[image]

But when I declare it globally, then nothing happens.

```
class newPhotoUpload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Second.this);
    Intent viewIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        dialog.show();
    }
```

[image]

Why is this happening??

Comment: Once try with creating the object inside `onPreExecute()`, I mean reference as global.

Comment: I tried it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Put your progress bar as a global variable (below `MainActivity extends Activity`) like,

```
ProgressDialog dialog=null;
```

Then

```
class newPhotoUpload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Intent viewIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Second.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure?Whats happening now? if you can share the full java page

Comment: The dialog box is not showing.When I create the object locally the dialog box is shown.But when I try to do it globally nothing.

Comment: but in you code above.it didnt declare the variable globally.

Comment: You have to declare the progress dialog GLOBALLY and define it inside onPreExcecute()